# How to increase root partition in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

In my case, I have /home partition inside the extended partition, I want to increase the space of / partition. How to do that?

Swapoff sda5 and resize sda6 doesn't work for me.
P.S. I do not want to lose any data.

[gparted sceenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfWec.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the partition, the resize/move button will be enabled. That will allow you to increase the size of the existing partition. See also [this link](https://www.rootusers.com/use-gparted-to-increase-disk-size-of-a-linux-native-partition/) for more information.

As for your specific scenario: First increase the size of the extended partition, then the home partition.

Warning: While this should be possible without losing files, it is still strongly advised to backup your files before continuing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot directly increase the size of the extended partition. When I chose extended partition, the resize/move button was blocked.

Comment: Ok, what about after creating a new linux swap at the empty end of the drive and removing the former one?